# Android Distorted UI

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, screen-orientation

I am not able to find the root cause of the below distortion.

UI works fine but when I rotate the screen to landscape, the UI gets distorted while scrolling. 
This distortion continues when the screen is again rotated to portrait.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/i_details" />

        <include layout="@layout/v_details" />

        <include layout="@layout/d_details" />
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

**UPDATE**

i_details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Message"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="RANDOM TEXT"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

v_details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navigateFab"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="navigation"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_24dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="2dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/map"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_24dp"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/website"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_language_24dp"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

d_details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Random Text"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:text="Random Text"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_24dp"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:text="Random Text"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:text="Random Text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_24dp"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:text="Random Text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE 3**
added activity code and stated fragment logic

i_activity

```
public class MYActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MYActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitation);

        MYFragment myFragment = new MYFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        myFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'my_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_container, myFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        recreate();
    }
}
```

in Fragment, I fetch the ID passed from activity, populate my static UI,
initiate CURSOR LOADER

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Activity Created");
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSOR_LOADER, getArguments(), this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and
onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor cursor) 
fetch and populate my dynamic UI views directly. 
Not using any adapter as all views are simple text views.

Included layouts are simple layouts with LinearLayout as parent container and FrameLayout or LinearLayout as the child and other views.

I am using Picasso lib to load the static map.
**UPDATE 2**
Picasso is not the issue as after removing Picasso, the issue remains.

Device: Nexus 5 
Android OS: 6.0.1

[image]

Comment: add xml of included layout also

Comment: you also need to design a layout for landscape mode. then it will be fine.

Comment: you can also add this line in manifiest in the activity tag

        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" by adding this your layout will not be created again when you will rotate the screen

Comment: I have tried that... not resolving my issue !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your Fragment is created Twice on the orientation Change 
Check saveInstancestate before creating new Fragment Object.

```
private MYFragment myfragment;//define fragment globally

  if(savedInstanceState == null) {
       myfragment= new MYFragment();//set tag for fragment
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, headlines, FRAGMENT_TAG_STRING).commit(); // Use tags, it's simpler to deal with

    } else {
        myfragment= getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG_STRING);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing your XML as shown below in the sample.

Idea is - You need to keep entire thing in a Relative layout. Once you use Relative layout, it gives you the ability to place items one above another.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/activity_line_graph" 
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/one"/>

            <include layout="@layout/activity_my_stocks"
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/two"/>

            <include layout="@layout/widget_collection"
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/three"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Each include should,

1. an ID to be referred to.
2. also have width and height as otherwise, the placement of above or below is ignored. 
   Hope this helps and hey, I wish you have a wonderful birthday party :) wishes in advance!

Comment: will check it out.
thanks for the wish... still 5-6 months ;) :D

Comment: I see, could you please edit your included layouts to show the complete details? as of now it's cut off and does not show entire code.

Comment: We have a ScrollView -> LinearLayout -> LinearLayout -> RelativeLayout -> LinearLayout across. Could you please make LinearLayout as root for "v_details" and push the relativeLayout under it and try the solution I mentioned above once?

Comment: Sorry mate, hope you get some help and resolve soon. all the best!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106885/discussion-between-natarajan-raman-and-abhinav-tyagi).

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the invalidate() method of the decoreview when the orientation changed.

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         this.getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: The idea is to force the layout to be redrawn ... this is just a step to investigate... ok try to call recreate(); instead of this.getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate(); ...

Comment: still the same issue :(

Comment: ok first I think u need to add android:configChanges attribute to your activity tag in your manifest ... 
<activity android:name="TestActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation"> ...
then could you remove the if statement ... so your code will look like this ..
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    recreate();
}

Comment: Thats strange :( ... could you please paste the code of your Activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106888/discussion-between-abhinav-tyagi-and-mohanad-khouli).